"Upload symbol failed" while archiving and uploading a build through Xcode
While im archiving and uploading an build to the appstore connect through xcode im facing this error.

The archive did not include a SYM for the Flutter.framework with the UUIDs
[4C4C44D2-5555-3144-A107-7B9E8F9E2FF7]. Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes a
DWARF file for Flutter.framework with the expected

It's saying dSYM is not included in the archive. I'm using macos15 with xcode version 16.0
Error image
Is there anything that I need to change or add to the project?

I discovered this error after updating to macOS 15 and Xcode 16.0. The previous archive, which didn't show an error during validation before the update, now shows this error during validation. I'll try to send the app to Connect with this error.

Yeah, it worked perfectly fine on earlier macos and xcode version. But after update it's showing this error. Has anyone got any solution / ideas how to solve them?

You can fix this issue by simply updating to the latest version of Flutter.

Check Build Settings: Ensure that Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM File for both the Debug and Release configurations:
Go to Xcode > Your Project > Build Settings.
Set Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File for all configurations.
